# Apex test class for covering site.login and it's exceptions

Tags: apex, community, code-coverage

I'm currently having an issue in covering site.login and its exceptions in our test method. The exceptions are handled to cover the failed logins in our portal. This exception thrown from apex is System.SecurityException. I tried to write test method for site.login but it seems that the site.login is always returning null for valid or invalid user.

Has any faced this issue OR any thoughts on this?

Here is our code :

```
  try {
        pr = Site.login(username, password, url);
        if(pr != null){
            success = true;   
        }
        else {
            errorMessage = ERRInvalid;
        }
    } catch(System.SecurityException se) {
        errorMessage = se.getMessage();
        success = false;
        if(user!=null){
            if(getNoOfFailedLogins(user.Id) == 4){
                errorMessage= EERR_ONEMORE_ATTEMPT_LEFT;
            }
            else if(IsLockedOut(user.Id)){
                errorMessage = ERRLockedOut;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: very much interesting to see `getNoOfFailedLogins`  & `IsLockedOut` code block ?  please share if possible.